# How to pass value from Page 1 to Page 2?

Tags: php

I'm kinda new to PHP and I want to pass the value from the *select* from a form in Page 1 to Page 2. Mind helping me? Thank you!

Comment: If u want to get help in future from this site, u should accept the answer that helps u, so that any other person who faced the same problem like u found this helpful also.... Click the gray Tick mark to accept an answer...

Comment: possible duplicate of [pass value from page to another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834153/pass-value-from-page-to-another-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

To pass a values purely from one page to another in PHP you need to start out with the HTML  element.

**On page1.php**

```
<form name='myForm' method='POST' action='page2.php'>
  <input type='text' name='myText' value=''>
  <button type='submit'>Submit</submit>
</form>
```

**On page2.php**

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

In a nutshell, the possible form methods are GET and POST.  a GET variable gets sent over on the URL, so you would end up at: `page2.php?myText=someValue` which is great for pages which you want to be bookmarkable such as search pages, perhaps - but utterly useless for things like passwords (just don't!).

POST values get sent in headers - you don't see any evidence of them as a user unless you are looking at the headers that get sent with the page request.  Obviously you can't bookmark a page with POSTed values, but its good for passing info between two pages.

The 'action' attribute in your form tag tells the browser where to submit the form to - its valid to set this as `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>` if you want the form page to post back to itself, without worrying about changing filenames.

As you might have already deduced - you can add your SELECT as well as other INPUT elements within the form, and post many values at once.  If you want to send something thats not user input, but is important to get onto page 2, look at `<input type='hidden'>`

If you want information to be persistent across the entire visit to the site - called the session, then you need to look at `$_SESSION` variables and all thats associated with them.

Comment: What I want to do is that get the value from the selected drop down list in page 1 and pass it to the text box in page 2. I don't really know how..

Comment: use a <select name='mySelect'> element within the posted form, and on page 2, if you're creating a text element, try <input name='myInput' value='<?php echo $_POST['mySelect']; ?>'

Answer (score 1):

All answers above are correct (based on the fact that you would combine cookie/session with post/get values to save them longer), however deciding how long and where the information should be available is a question you need to ask yourself.

Do you want to transfer information from page 1 to page 2? Than a $_GET method or a $_POST method are probably the options you are looking for.

$_GET are variables stored in the URL like:
index.php?variable=value&another=val

You can send these variables by simply adding them to a link you can click on or by setting a forms-method to get ().

$_POST are variables send via a post form. These ofter are needed when you want to send multiple parameters to another page which are different from each user (so data that can be inserted by a user him/herself). This requires the form method to be "post" ().

If you want data to be available across multiple pages (login details for example) you might want to look for $_SESSION or $_COOKIE. They are similar to eachother, but a session only keeps the data for as long as a user is on your webpage. A cookie on the other hand can have a timeperiod assigned (1 day, 1 week, 1 month, 1 hour, etc) so you can control the length of time this data is available.

Another option is to save data into a database using a users IP adres for example to connect the data to a user. However I don't think this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple select:

first page:

```
<form name='form' method='POST' action='page2.php'>
    <select name='selectedValue'>
        <option value='apple'>apple</option>
        <option value='banana'>banana</option>
    </select>
    <button type='submit'>Submit</submit>
</form>
```

second page:

```
<?php
    echo ($_POST['selectedValue']);
?>
```

I recently discovered a how to use multiple select that you might like to use:

first page:

```
<form name='form' method='POST' multiple='multiple' action='page2.php'>
    <select name='selectedValue[]'>
        <option value='apple'>apple</option>
        <option value='banana'>banana</option>
    </select>
    <button type='submit'>Submit</submit>
</form>
```

second page:

```
<?php
    foreach ($_POST['selectedValue'] as $fruit) {
        echo ($fruit);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either [GET or POST](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php).

Comment: Session is based on cookies and is only possible after using POST to the server

Comment: @Salman A — You can't store the value in a select in the session until it has been sent to the server, so that simply won't work. You could add the data to a cookie using JavaScript, but that would be unnecessarily complicated and add a pointless dependancy on JS.

Comment: That's my point, they all rely on either HTTP GET / POST, downvote anyone?

Comment: What I want to do is that get the value from the selected drop down list in page 1 and pass it to the text box in page 2. I don't really know how..

Comment: @edmondson: Did OP change the question? Either that or I missed the part where he said *from a form*. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Set the `action` of the form to page2.php. Submit the form. Then use `$_GET['the_name_of_the_select']` (or `$_POST` if you set the form's `method` to post).

Comment: This method lead to change the existing action of the form hence a huge change in the code

Comment: What I want to do is that get the value from the selected drop down list in page 1 and pass it to the text box in page 2. I don't really know how..

Comment: @Shakti Singh — no, it doesn't. It assumes the form is still being written. There is no evidence of any current state of the form in the code at present.

Comment: @jeje_13 — once you have the data, you just run it though `htmlspecialchars()` and output it in the page.

Comment: @Quentin: Form is already written and He stuck there that's why come up with a question

Comment: @Shakti Singh — The question doesn't include the form. It doesn't state that the form can't be changed. Setting the action to the page you want to send the data to is how forms are supposed to work.

Comment: @Quentin: True, nothing is stated, ans also he said Page 1 and Page 2 (Web Page) Not `page1.php,page2.php` Then Why my approach is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Look at [sessions](http://php.net/book.session).

Comment: You have to get the data to PHP before you can put it in a session. Since the question stated that the data was a value of a select element, and that value depends on which option the user picks, sessions are useless for this.

Comment: Its not a session question - its about getting data from a page containing a form into a page that receives the form data.

Comment: Nowhere does the OP mention he wants to POST to a different page. If he posts to the same page, SESSIONS are a good way to go. Unless i'm not understanding the question?

Comment: As I understand the OP, he doesn't know about GET and POST, and he says he wants to 'pass a value from a select on a form to page 2' which to me is a pretty clear question about forms and GET/POST.

Comment: Oh, indeed, may be he is asking about getting information, I understood as if he asking to pass data between multiply pages.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @sixeightzero: You are right and thanks for suggestion. My answer is way too short and it would be useful to describe basic idea in the answer and add link as further reading.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand how client/server works.

Page1 and Page2 exist on the server, but are rendered at each client. So, assuming the form is posted to Page1, the server can't just "pass" data from one page to another.

What you need to do is, on "Page1" store the values somewhere, and in Page2 get the stored values.

Since you don't want ALL your visitors to get the data from one single visitor, you must store this information in a way that you can relate to the visitor. This means:

- Session data
- Cookies
- Database with field(s) identifying the visitor

Answer (score 0):

there are so many teq to pass the values

you can use the form ,and pass it to second form 
also you can use the session to store there value
also you can add it to URL 
for exampe: header(stachover.php?name1&name2)

name1 , name2 these the values

if you didn't figure this , i can show you an example