# Pass PHP variable from one page to another and to another

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [pass value from page to another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834153/pass-value-from-page-to-another-in-php)

For example, I have 3 pages. First page will be a regular HTML login page which will ask for username. Second page will get this username variable thru POST function and assign a php variable such as $username. Third page will take this $username variable and display it. How can this be done? I have done the first two pages but I need help with passing it to the third page. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Check the PHP documentation for sessions. There are many examples of how to do this.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Answer (score 1):

Use a $_SESSION superglobal:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

You'll need to use a [session_start()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) function at the beginning of any page you want to maintain session data for. After that, you can just assign to and retrieve from $_SESSION['username'].